# RDS - boto - how to get results from read_replica_dbinstance_identifiers?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-rds

According to my understanding of the `boto.rds.dbinstance` class, I should be able to get a variable named `read_replica_dbinstance_identifiers` from the object, but I cannot and I don't understand why. I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

When I run `rds-describe-db-instances --quiet --show-xml` I definitely can find my read replicas in the XML:

```
<ReadReplicaDBInstanceIdentifiers>
  <ReadReplicaDBInstanceIdentifier>my-dbinstance-id-1</ReadReplicaDBInstanceIdentifier>
  <ReadReplicaDBInstanceIdentifier>my-dbinstance-id-2</ReadReplicaDBInstanceIdentifier>
</ReadReplicaDBInstanceIdentifiers>
```

But when I use boto to get the same information with a test script like the one below, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'DBInstance' object has no attribute 'read_replica_dbinstance_identifiers'
```

The script looks like this:

```
import boto
dbinstanceid = 'my-dbinstance-id'
rds = boto.connect_rds()
instances = rds.get_all_dbinstances(dbinstanceid)
for i in instances:
    for property, value in vars(i).iteritems():
        print property, ": ", value
print "============================="

print i, " ", i.id
print "connection: ", i.connection
print 'db instance identifiers: ', i.ReadReplicaDBInstanceIdentifiers
print i.read_replica_dbinstance_identifiers
```

My version of boto, according to pip is:
Name: boto
Version: 2.9.7
Location: `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the read_replica_dbinstance_identifiers method instead?

If I am reading correctly you have pulled down your instances in an array and are looping through them with each one as 'i'

so you should be able to:
print i.read_replica_dbinstance_identifiers or something similar

If you ever get stuck with problems like this:

print dir(i) #Is VERY useful to see what is possible on that object

Now to go and implement tags for RDS :-( loooooong!